# Custom Control with Localization Support in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created the DateTimePicker control. Now i want to add localization Support with this.

I have followed the below steps.

> 1. Created CustomControls.de-DE.resx inside the ResourceFolder.
> 2. added some commonly used strings in that resx file
> 3. changed the access modifier to Public
> 4. added `<SupportedCulture>de-DE;</SupportedCulture>` in the csproj file.
> 5. set System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"); in sample.cs file before
>      IntializeComponent().
> 6. my DateTimevalue was " 2 Day(s): 3 Hr (s): 5 Min(s) : 32 Sec (s)

Getting only default language that is english.

What i did wrong? Please help me anyone. Is anything i missed?

Comment: Try changing the CurrentUICulture in the app.xaml.cs constructor instead of the page!

Comment: I tried this. but no changes.

Comment: Is there different between adding the properties/Resoures.resx and adding Resources/Resources.resx?

Comment: Don't think so, but normally I add mine under the Properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clear Steps To add Localization Supports in WP7**

> 1. Create Custom control.
> 2. Add AppResource.resx inside Properties
> 3. Add AppResource.es.resx and Appresource.it.resx files inside Properties
> 4. Add needed strings with unique name.(we can refer the strings use of this id).
> 5. Add it;es; in the csproj file.(unload the project, rightclick->edit, add the supportedculture
>      tag then reload it)
> 6. Create the Sample
> 7. do the same as 5th step for Sample.csproj file
> 8. Change the cultures of System in the button click.(Ex: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
>      System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");)
> 9. Run the Project

Ref: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step

Thankyou.