# Changing string depending on Culture

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to display the string "**Hello**" in the TextBlock. If the Culture is **fr-FR**,
then it should be displayed as "**Bonjour**" in WP7.

**Solution**: [My Localization Support Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837103/custom-control-with-localization-support-in-wp7)

Working File now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use string tables and localization. This old Ted Pattison article explains it well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx